# React выплывающее окно

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть две компоненты родительская и дочерняя (header). Как сделать так чтоб при клике на элемент в хедере окошко всплывало, на на клик в любой области за этим окошком окно скрывалось

Comment: Вопрос совсем непонятен...

Comment: вопспользовалась данным решением, установила соответсвенно библиотеку npm install semantic-ui-react, все сработало но в консоли теперь ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста что делать? [![введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTbaE.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTbaE.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется модальное окно (modal window)
Чтобы не изобретать велосипед, необходимо воспользоваться библиотеками, к примеру: 1) компонент Modal из semantic-ui-react 2) react-modal

Дальше пишете:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Button, Header, Icon, Modal } from 'semantic-ui-react'

export default class ModalExampleControlled extends Component {
  state = { modalOpen: false }

  handleOpen = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: true })

  handleClose = () => this.setState({ modalOpen: false })

  render() {
    return (
      <Modal
        trigger={<Button onClick={this.handleOpen}>Show Modal</Button>}
        open={this.state.modalOpen}
        onClose={this.handleClose}
        basic
        size='small'
      >
        <Header icon='browser' content='Cookies policy' />
        <Modal.Content>
          <h3>This website uses cookies to ensure the best user experience.</h3>
        </Modal.Content>
        <Modal.Actions>
          <Button color='green' onClick={this.handleClose} inverted>
            <Icon name='checkmark' /> Got it
          </Button>
        </Modal.Actions>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Если клик на элемент в компоненте "А", должен влиять на компонент "Б", то вам нужен глобальный стор. Например: [Redux](https://redux.js.org/docs/introduction/).

Алгоритм простой: по клику меняем значение переменной в сторе, а в компоненте2 вешаем\снимаем класс в зависимости от значения этой переменной, или вообще рендерим\не рендерим блок.

2) Для того, чтобы обработать событие клика "вне" элемента, можно воспользоваться [HOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-onclickoutside).